# Access Axis M1013 camera in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I'm trying to access the video stream from an Axis M1013 camera using OpenCV. I'm trying to get the video by using `VideoCapture`, but all of the urls that I try to open don't return anything. I can access the Live View of the camera through my browser, but if I put in the urls that are supposed to return a video stream, I either get nothing or "No session ID specified." How do I access the MJPG video feed?

I've tried the following urls:

```
http://<user>:<password>@<ip>:554/mjpg/1/video.mjpg
http://<user>:<password>@<ip>:554/mjpg/video.mjpg
http://<user>:<password>@<ip>/mjpg/1/video.mjpg
http://<user>:<password>@<ip>/mjpg/video.mjpg
http://<user>:<password>@<ip>:554/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi
http://<user>:<password>@<ip>/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi
```

But none of them work.

My code is:

```
VideoCapture vCap;
vCap.open("http://<user>:<password>@<ip>:554/mjpg/1/video.mjpg");
```

And the error I get is:

```
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file http://<user>:<password>@<ip>:554/mjpg/1/video.mjpg
```

(Of course, I'm using the actual username, password, and camera ip)

I'm using OpenCV version 2.4.9 with C++ and an Axis M1013 camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was just that I did not have ffmpeg properly installed so OpenCV could not decode the mjpg video stream. Once I reinstalled ffmpeg and OpenCV using [this tutorial](http://tech.enekochan.com/en/2012/07/27/install-opencv-2-4-2-with-ffmpeg-support-in-mac-os-x-10-8/), it worked fine.